# Find xml files from jackrabbit with specified tag name

Tags: xml, lucene, full-text-search, jackrabbit

I'm using jackrabbit to store some xml files with the following code

```
public Node saveFile(Node folder, String nodeName, InputStream inputStream, String mimeType, String encoding) throws RepositoryException {
    Node fileNode = folder.addNode(nodeName, JcrConstants.NT_FILE);
    Node resourceNode = fileNode.addNode(JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT, JcrConstants.NT_RESOURCE);

    resourceNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_MIMETYPE, mimeType);
    resourceNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_ENCODING, encoding);
    resourceNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA, createBinary(folder.getSession(), inputStream));

    return fileNode;
}

private Binary createBinary(Session session, InputStream inputStream) throws RepositoryException {
        return session.getValueFactory().createBinary(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
    }
```

The mimeType is set to **text/xml**, I'm using the full text search function and it works fine when I try to search files by some content as keywords, but now I want to search files by xml tag name, currently it seems the tag names are not in the lucene indexes so it returns nothing, how could I make this work with jackrabbit? My SearchIndex config is as follows:

```
 <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
        <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true"/>
        <param name="minMergeDocs" value="100"/>
        <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="3"/>
        <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="100000"/>
        <param name="mergeFactor" value="10"/>
        <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000"/>
        <param name="bufferSize" value="10"/>
        <param name="cacheSize" value="1000"/>
        <param name="forceConsistencyCheck" value="false"/>
        <param name="autoRepair" value="true"/>
        <param name="analyzer" value="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
        <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl"/>
        <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="true"/>
        <param name="resultFetchSize" value="2147483647"/>
        <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <param name="extractorTimeout" value="5000"/>
        <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100"/>
    </SearchIndex>
```

Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML tag names are not indexed by default. So you will need to take care of that yourself. 
Jackkrabbit uses Apache Tika for text extraction. So you can easily extract the required information by implementing your own xml parser that extends org.apache.tika.parser.Parser

Answer (score 0):

Xml tag is not indexed by default, you need to extract xml tag names by yourself and index it according your requirements.